# How do I permanently change environment variables via terminal? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, login

I clobbered my environment variables, so now when I attempt to log into the desktop I get sent back to my login screen after a short blackout of the screen. I've attempted to use 'export' but that only works for the current terminal session. Every other answer I've read has mentioned using gedit, which I don't have access to.

How should I change it? I found an answer stating that it should be changed to "/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin".

Comment: It would probably be useful to explain *how* you clobbered the variables. You should have access to the `nano` editor via the CLI e.g. `/usr/bin/sudo nano /etc/environment`. You can also copy default `.profile` and `.bashrc` files from `/etc/skel` if those are what got "clobbered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export` will set them during that session.

What you wrote is the content of one of the variables. The `PATH` variable.

To check what it's currently set to, you can use,

```
echo $PATH
```

From a terminal.

This can be overrides for your user on multiple places. Most common would be a few hidden files on your home directory.

Check the following files,

```
.profile
.bashrc
.bash_profile
```

See if you find a line that references the `PATH`

You can post here the content.